# Why do I get 0x5 as a response when sending SPI command cmd0?

Tags: c, spi, tms570

I use a TMS570LS3137HDK development board test in SPI mode to use micro SD card.

My micro SD card is a SanDisk Ultra 16GB HC.

When I use SPI `send cmd0` to initialize SD card, it responses `0x5`, but should answer `0x01` instead.

Here is my code.

```
gioInit();
sciInit();
spiInit();

gioSetBit(spiPORT2, SPI_PIN_CS1, 1);
gioSetBit(spiPORT2, SPI_PIN_CS0, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    spiTransmitAndReceiveData(spiREG2, &spiDat1, 1, (uint16 *) 0xFF, NULL);
}

uint16_t cmd0[6] = {0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x95};
uint16_t resultData[6] = {0};

spiDAT1_t spiDat1;
spiDat1.CS_HOLD = CS_HOLD;
spiDat1.WDEL = WDEL;
spiDat1.DFSEL = DFSEL;
spiDat1.CSNR = CSNR;

gioSetBit(spiPORT2, SPI_PIN_CS0, 0);
spiTransmitAndReceiveData(spiREG2, &spiDat1, 6, cmd0, resultData);
gioSetBit(spiPORT2, SPI_PIN_CS0, 1);
```

I tried to change CLK and loop `cmd0` but that did not work.

Comment: What does response 0x5 mean?